# Mover el texto junto al movimiento del botón

Tags: android, material-design

Tengo un pequeño problema en el diseño de un botón para mi aplicación Android. He creado un botón con efecto 3D como el que se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image]
*(1º Normal, 2º Pulsado.)*

Pero, si te has dado cuenta, cuando se pulsa el botón, el texto no se mueve con el resto de elementos hacia abajo, si no que se mantiene en el mismo sitio y esto hace el se pierda el efecto de botón. Tendría que verse como en la imagen siguiente:

[image]

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como poder solucionar esto?

Este es mi código:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/WelcomeImage"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btStart"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Start"
        android:background="@drawable/button3d"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Este es el código del efecto 3D del botón:

`button3d.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#A6A6A6" />
                    <corners android:radius="7.0dip" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="4.0dip">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="7.0dip" />
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape >
                    <padding android:top="4.0dip" />
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="7.0dip" />
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Gracias por adelantado.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

La respuesta de [x4mp73r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10751/4684) es una autentica maravilla, pero encontré unos fallos que os vendría bien saber, incluso a x4mp73r.

El primero de ellos aparece cuando has implementado la función `setOnTouchListener()`, porque cuando pulsas en el botón, el efecto del texto aparece correctamente, pero cuando sin soltar el dedo de la pantalla, lo arrastras hacia fuera del botón, este mismo vuelve a su esta normal y el texto sigue con el `padding` que le toca porque aún estas tocando la pantalla. Es lioso de explicar y no os lo puedo mostrar con imágenes, pero si alguien utiliza esto, que pruebe a pulsar el botón y sin soltar, arrastrar el dedo hacia fuera del botón y se entenderá perfectamente.

Una solución simple fue separar el código del archivo `button3d.xml` en dos y hacer que el método `OnTouch` del botón manejara el cambio del `padding` y del `background` de la siguiente forma:

`button3d_normal.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#A6A6A6" />
                    <corners android:radius="7.0dip" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="4.0dip">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="7.0dip" />
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item> 
</selector>
```

`button3d_pressed.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <padding android:top="4.0dip" />
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="7.0dip" />
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`activity_main.xml`

Solo cambiaría el botón:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btStart"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/startIntro"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button3d_normal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
btStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btStart);
btStart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    btStart.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.button3d_pressed));
                    btStart.setPadding(0, px, 0, 0);
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    btStart.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.button3d_normal));
                    btStart.setPadding(0, 0, 0, px);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

El ultimo problema fue que si implementaba las views `OnTouchListener` y `OnClickListener` en la clase y asignaba los dos a un botón (en el mismo orden), el `setOnClickListener` no me funcionaba.

La solución me trajo de cabeza pero fue muy sencilla. El método `onTouch` devuelve un valor booleano, si ese valor lo devolvemos como `true`, querrá decir que ya hemos terminado con cualquier acción de este botón y que no se implementara nada más aparte, pero si devolvemos `false` será todo lo contrario y podemos seguir aplicándole más funciones al mismo botón.

Espero que os sirva a todos, estos botones quedan genial en una aplicación.

Comment: Hola, estuve viendo tu codigo pero estoy teniendo problemas. No logro que el padding vuelva a su posición original cuando se deja de hacer foco en el botón. ¿A vos te anduvo tal como lo describis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que existen muchas soluciones, una de ellas es hacer uso de `setPadding` por medio de `onTouchListener` a tu botón:

```
tuBotón.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
        if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { 
            //Colocas el padding que necesites          
        } else if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //Colocas el padding que necesites               
        }   
        return true; 
    } 
});
```

Los padding pueden ser mas o menos así:

```
setPadding(left, top, right, bottom); // Botón normal
setPadding(left, top + x, right, bottom - x); // Botón presionado
```

Otra opción es intentando agregar esta propiedad a tu botón:

```
android:gravity="bottom|center"
```

o bien:

```
android:layout_weight="0"
```

Espero y te sea de utilidad.